# AWS IAM user sso login

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sso

I'm trying to login using awscli in console with a IAM user I created
Steps I followed

- Created the IAM user using the root user with `AdministratorAccess`, let's call the user `james`
- Created access keys for `james` and downloaded/copy them
- Configured awscli in local machine with

  ```
  [default]
   aws_access_key_id = XXX
   aws_secret_access_key = YYY
   sso_start_url = https://zzz.awsapps.com/start
   sso_account_id = 999888
   sso_region = eu-north-1
  ```
- Logged in as `james` in https://999888.signin.aws.amazon.com/console and then went to https://console.aws.amazon.com/singlesignon/ and enabled sso login
- Finally tried to connect from local machine using `aws sso login`

It successfully opens the browser and redirects with the code it shows a login page where it asks for a `username` (and then a password) I'm using the username `james` and trying with its password but it fails with `We couldn't verify your sign-in credentials. Please try again.`

Could you help me clear what am I missing? Thanks for the help in advance. Hope it's clear enough

Comment: AWS SSO is used when you want users to authenticate via an external directory service such as Active Directory. In this situation, the username and password is managed _outside_ of AWS and AWS will 'trust' the external service to say whether a user can login. **Is this what you are wanting to achieve?** If so, you do _not_ need to create an IAM User, but you will need to configure SSO (now called 'IAM Identity Center') to connect to your external authentication service.

Comment: Exactly what I wanted to achieve. Thanks for the comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want users to authenticate via an external service such as Active Directory, **do not create an IAM User**. Instead, users will authenticate themselves against the external identity store.

Instead, configure **AWS IAM Identity Center**.

From [What is IAM Identity Center? (successor to AWS Single Sign-On)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/singlesignon/latest/userguide/what-is.html):

> With AWS IAM Identity Center (successor to AWS Single Sign-On), you can manage sign-in security for your workforce identities, also known as workforce users. IAM Identity Center provides one place where you can create or connect workforce users and centrally manage their access across all their AWS accounts and applications. You can use multi-account permissions to assign your workforce users access to AWS accounts. You can use application assignments to assign your users access to IAM Identity Center enabled applications, cloud applications, and customer Security Assertion Markup Language (SAML 2.0) applications.

The basic configuration steps are:

- Enable IAM Identity Center
- Choose your identity source (eg an Active Directory server)
- Configure Administration users
- Configure permission sets

See: [Getting started - AWS IAM Identity Center](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/singlesignon/latest/userguide/getting-started.html)